# Call C# dll library methods from Silverlight 5 via PInvoke

Tags: c#, pinvoke, silverlight-5.0, unmanaged

I know I cannot add reference to c# dll library in Silverlight application if it's not Silverlight library. 
But I've a question - can I treat this dll like unmanaged code and use PInvoke like with C/C++ libraries ? 
I had try with sample project dll library:

```
namespace TestLib
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public static int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

And in my silverlight application:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("TestLib.dll", EntryPoint = "TestLib.Add", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int Add(int x, int y);
```

but I'm getting an error while trying to invoke method:

> Unable to find an entry point named 'TestLib.Add' in DLL

and if I try without namespace:

> Unable to find an entry point named 'Add' in DLL

Can You point me with some hits ? Note, I've also tried to compile this dll as Silverlight application but there are some methods unsupported by Silverlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use COM for interop with your C# dll rather than trying Pinvoke.  Expose some classes in you dll as COM objects, then use JavaScript to create those COM objects, and call their functions.

```
  var progid = "TestLib.MyObject";
  var TestLibObject = new ActiveXObject(progid);
  var result = TestLibObject.Add(1, 2);
```

Once I had the JavaScript calls working with the COM object I wrapped them in a class to represent the COM object in Silverlight.

```
public class MyObject
{
  string varName = "myObject";
  public MyObject()
  {
    string js = "var " + varName + " = new ActiveXObject(\"TestLib.MyObject\");"
    HtmlPage.Window.Eval(js);
  }
  public int Add(int x, int y)
  {
    string js = string.Format("{0}.Add({1},{3});", varName, x, y);
    return (int)HtmlPage.Window.Eval(js);
  }
}
```

You may want to refer to [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645031(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645031%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to see how manages types are passed to/from JavaScript.

If you still want to use Pinvoke you could try [UnmanagedExports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports).  It adds a DllExport attribute that you can use to expose a function to native code.  You should then be able to Pinvoke this function.

In my own project I had success with using COM/JavaScript for interop in Silverlight.  I haven't tried UnmanagedExports/Pinvoke in Silverlight.

Comment: ok that's something, thank You. although the best solution for me would be not to modify this c# dll. but it seems I'm asking to much ;)

Comment: If modifying the original dll isn't an option, you could make your own wrapper dll to expose items from your TestLib.dll.  The wrapper would then be exposed to com, and in turn would make calls to your dll.  You could also use C++/CLI to create a wrapper dll which mixes native and managed code.  You can expose functions to native code (for Pinvoke) which in turn call your managed code.
links (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9903/Calling-Managed-Code-from-Unmanaged-Code-and-vice, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35041/Mixing-NET-and-native-code)

Answer (score 0):

I think this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh560563%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is relevant to your problem.
It seems to be possible, but your DLL isn't in C#, is it ? Because if it is then a PInvoke might not works.

Comment: That's my problem - it's written in C#. Also I cannot use this DLL in WCF service, it has to be on client PC. This library is about scaner device operation and has to be invoke on user side.

Comment: I think you're stuck with it, you may try to scan using a standard windows library which will present on client side

Comment: I could but there's lots of helper classes in this dll. Life's hard ;)

Comment: Yes, it's indeed hard when falling back from .net to standard PInvoke calls...
If your question is answered remember to check the flag for it ;)

Comment: Ok, I'll wait a little longer, maybe there's some solution - if not than You're right and it'll be my painfull answer ;)